# given a Task instance, can I tell if ContinueWith has been called on it?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

Given a `Task` instance, how can I tell if `ContinueWith` has been called on it? I want to know if I'm the last task executing in a chain.

```
Task task = Task.FromResult();
void SomeMethod(var x) {
   task = task.ContinueWith(previous => {
       if (task.ContinueWith is called) return;
       // do something with x...
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help in the general case. The `ContinueWith` may not have been the last one.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I'm not sure I understand your statement. Perhaps my example is too lame. I'm interested in a scenario where three tasks are created. The first one finishes because it got started. The second (and all middle tasks) gets skipped because the third got added before the first one finished.

Comment: Perhaps a better example of your actual problem eould make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant multiple continuations. A possible solution may be like this.

```
class Program
    {
        public class TaskState
        {
            public bool Ended { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var task = Task.FromResult("Stackoverflow");
            var state = new TaskState();
            task.ContinueWith((result, continuationState) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("in first");


            }, state).ContinueWith((result, continuationState) =>
            {
                if (!state.Ended)
                    Console.WriteLine("in second");
                state.Ended = true;

            }, state).ContinueWith((result, continuationState) =>
            {
                if (!state.Ended)
                    Console.WriteLine("in third");
                state.Ended = true;

            }, state);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have a static variable (a dictionary object) declared on the parent and update it with unique keyvalues when your Tasks are triggered. You can monitor this static variable to see if all the other threads has completed the execution or not.

Comment: Imagine my software runs for a long time. I don't know when all the tasks are done because it's not quantifiable. I just want to skip tasks that aren't the most recent request.

Comment: Thinking more on it, though, maybe all I do need is some kind of incrementing variable that I increment before calling ContinueWith and compare against a local copy inside my execute.

Comment: Yes, that should work. It is, otherwise, difficult to track the information as each of those tasks run independent of each other